# Android Studio armv7 project

Tags: android, assembly, armv7

I'm trying to run these projects which uses jni to do a arm assembly call im using android studio but it has external makefiles im a little bit lost

https://github.com/Miouyouyou/ARMv7-Java-JNI-call

https://github.com/Miouyouyou/ARMv7-Java-JNI-return

I am using android studio on windows, when i try to do make using the android studio terminal (using gnu make) i get

armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi-as -o decypherArcane.o decypherArcane.s
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi-as -o decypher
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [decypherArcane.o] Error 2

i think it will perhaps work if i convert the makefile into a .bat one

This is the makefile (it is outside the root of the android studio project)

```
`CROSS_COMPILE = armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi-
LD = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld.gold
AS = $(CROSS_COMPILE)as
ANDROID_APK_NATIVE_LIB_DIR = ./apk/app/src/main/jniLibs
ANDROID_LIBNAME = libarcane.so
SOURCE = decypherArcane.s
OBJECT = decypherArcane.o

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJECT)
    $(LD) -shared --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker --hash-style=sysv -o $(ANDROID_LIBNAME) $(OBJECT)
    mkdir -p $(ANDROID_APK_NATIVE_LIB_DIR)/armeabi{,-v7a}
    cp $(ANDROID_LIBNAME) $(ANDROID_APK_NATIVE_LIB_DIR)/armeabi
    cp $(ANDROID_LIBNAME) $(ANDROID_APK_NATIVE_LIB_DIR)/armeabi-v7a

.PHONY: install
install: all
    make -C apk

$(OBJECT): $(SOURCE)
    $(AS) -o $(OBJECT) $(SOURCE)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECT) $(ANDROID_LIBNAME)

.PHONY: distclean
distclean: clean
    $(RM) $(ANDROID_APK_NATIVE_LIB_DIR)/armeabi/$(ANDROID_LIBNAME)
    $(RM) $(ANDROID_APK_NATIVE_LIB_DIR)/armeabi-v7a/$(ANDROID_LIBNAME)
`
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated these two projects, [ARMv7-Java-JNI-return](https://github.com/Miouyouyou/ARMv7-Java-JNI-return) and [ARMv7-Java-JNI-call](https://github.com/Miouyouyou/ARMv7-Java-JNI-call), making the build process slightly easier on Windows.

You'll need :

- The Android NDK path in your `PATH` environment variable.
- A Java JDK to compile and install the sample APK

For each project :

- Browse the folder where you cloned the repository
- Open a *Command window* here using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd> → **Open a Command window here**
- Type `mkBuild`

If everything goes fine, you should see something like this :

```
[armeabi] Compile arm    : arcane <= decypherArcane.s
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libarcane.so
[armeabi] Install        : libarcane.so => apk/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libarcane.so
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm    : arcane <= decypherArcane.s
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libarcane.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libarcane.so => apk/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libarcane.so
```

If that's the case, plug your phone and type the following in the opened *Command Window* :

```
cd apk
gradlew installDebug
```

Again, if everything goes fine, then your phone should have a new Android APP named either *Decyph'App* or *Wild Assembly !*. Run the new app and see the results.

Now, if you run into any issue while trying to build, install or run these samples, please open an issue ticket on Github or Gitlab mirrors.